# Does Kerkis font work with xelatex?

Tags: fonts, fontspec, ubuntu

I'm a confused on whether xelatex and kerkis font can be used together. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10, Tex Live 2013/Debian, and I have the kerkis font installed. Though, if I try to compile the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{kerkis}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Kerkis}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Hi!
\end{document}
```

I get the following errors:

> /usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/web2c/mktexnam: Could not map source
>   abbreviation K for Kerkis. ... snip ... kpathsea: Running mktexmf
>   Kerkis ! I can't find file `Kerkis'. <*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1;
>   nonstopmode; input Kerkis ... snip ... kpathsea: Running mktexmf
>   Kerkis ! I can't find file`Kerkis'. <*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1;
>   nonstopmode; input Kerkis

I've searched into tex.stackexchange.com and it appears as if Kerkis works only with Babel. Is there a definitive answer? If the answer is no, what other fonts do you suggest instead ? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Just a hint: When you load `xltxtra` you do not need anymore to load `fontspec` explicitely – it will be done under the hood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need the TrueType or OpenType version of Kerkis. You can download them from the University of the Aegean site in the [Kerkis page](http://iris.math.aegean.gr/kerkis/). Decompress the `.zip` files; install the fonts and use them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Kerkis}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

An image of the Properties of the document above after processing:

[image]

The Copyright belongs to the The Department of Mathematics of the University of the Aegean, Karlobasi, and the site explicitly has the follwoing warning:

> If you want to use this font family in commercial work (like in books)
>   you *must* include in the Copyright section the fact that you are
>   using "Kerkis (C) Department of Mathematics, University of the
>   Aegean".

Comment: I'm asking myself why they aren't included in TeX Live

Comment: @egreg Perhaps a copyright issue? The Copyright belongs to the The Department of Mathematics of the University of the Aegean, Karlobasi, so this might impose some restriction to include them in TeX Live.

Comment: Thank you! It worked! The font comprehension of *tex is beyond me.

Comment: So, I wonder, why when I do 'apt-cache search kerkis' I get 'texlive-lang-greek' as a result. Plus when I do 'find /usr -name "*kerkis*"' I get results under /usr/share/texlive/texmf. Are they in some other format than TTF ?

Comment: @Zet yes; the font in the package is not in TT format.

Comment: Thank you @GonzaloMedina :) Understanding provides such a relief.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina It is not true that you *must* use the truetype format. XeLaTeX *can* use type 1 fonts although you obviously lose most of the benefits of its font handling. This is explained in the `fontspec` manual on page 8 and illustrated in my answer below. I said there that this is mostly useful for fonts where there is no (affordable) otf/ttf option but it might also be useful in some cases if the type 1 is available under a different licence.

Answer (score 2):

Although you will probably prefer to install the truetype version of the fonts as explained in Gonzalo Medina's answer, it is not true that you *must* do so. You can use the type 1 fonts as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\newfontfamily\unicodefont{Latin Modern Roman}

\usepackage{kerkis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
This uses legacy fonts and will not support any fontspec features which rely on opentype/truetype font specifications.

{\unicodefont For this reason, you may also wish to define a font for unicode. This is explained on page 8 of the fontspec manual.}

\end{document}
```

[image: Mix of opentype Latin Modern Roman and Type 1 Kerkis]

See the `fontspec` manual for details. While this is not the best option for Kerkis, it might be the only (or only affordable) option for other fonts in type 1 format.

[image: Font properties from xelatex run]

Comment: I don't think that mixing Kerkis and Latin Modern is a good idea.

Comment: @egreg Of course not. I only picked Latin Modern because I happen to know its name and I'm not sure I've got Lucida Grande which is the example in the `fontspec` manual. I'm certainly not recommending using this particular combination of fonts. I just have a very hazy idea of which fonts I can use with XeLaTeX since I never actually use it. 'Latin Modern Roman' is pretty much the only one I'm sure about. So I always use it as my 'sample' opentype font. Aesthetically it would obviously be a horrible choice here but which fonts I have in opentype format is, in any case, irrelevant to the OP.